# openstreetmap overpass api and osmosis to get beach data not getting polygons

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, osmosis

I tried to collect beach data in a certain region. I used both overpass api and osmosis to extract beach from a pbf. Both worked. But from overpass api, i can get beach polygons (closed ways) and points (nodes), however, from osmosis, I can just get points (nodes). When I search in osmosis, I did include the ways and relations. Still, I didn't get beach polygons as i got from overpass.

Anyone may have some solutions or explanation? Many thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us how you are calling osmosis?

Comment: Definitely, I tried both:
osmosis --read-pbf file=planet-latest.osm.pbf --node-key-value keyValueList="natural.beach" --way-key-value keyValueList="natural.beach" --write-xml output.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately osmosis doesn't support using `--node-key-value` and `--way-key-value` together. You have to make multiple runs and then use `--merge` to merge the results. See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis for examples.

Comment: Many thanks, 
In this case, 

osmosis --read-xml file="XXX" -tag-filter accept-nodes keyValueList="natural.beach" --tag-filter accept-ways keyValueList="natural.beach" --write-xml file="XXX.osm"

probably doesn't work either because I try to get node and way together at one time, right ? Many thanks!

Comment: I guess so. Unfortunately I have very little experience with osmosis.